# Прописать команды в DevTools console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Мне нужно через консоль написать команды, изменяющие параметры отдельных элементов на веб странице. Как сделать это вручную, через вкладку Elements, понятно, но нужно именно через консоль.

Например, я обращаюсь к элементу через имя класса:

```
$(.'blackjack-seat__icon')
```

получаю

```
<div class="blackjack-score__bg"></div>
```

Мне нужно изменить эту иконку, этот элемент. Изменить параметры widht, color, opacity. Как это делается вручную, понятно на скриншоте.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Например, вот так `$(.'blackjack-seat__icon').style.width='100px';`

Answer (score 2):

Таким способом (как и в коде):

```
$('.blackjack-seat__icon').css({'width': '20%', 'opacity':'1', 'color':'red'});
```

И в самом начале у вас ошибка, должно быть так:

```
$('.blackjack-seat__icon')
```